# How to start with graphic design

Tags: information-graphics, pixel, art, graphic-styles, linux

I am new to this forum. I want to get started with graphic design. I have a linux OS , what software and books do i require to get started? Also i would like to start with pixel art . Hope you can guide me.

Comment: First way to start is research.  Maybe like using the search feature in sites as this question has been asked before.

Answer (score -2):

just google for pix art tutorials you get many video tutorials once you seen it, you get ideas from where to start.

HBK